# perl 500 certificate verify failed

Tags: perl, api, salesforce, lwp

I am using the WWW::Salesforce perl library to login and fetch some data. But I get this error on login -

> perl 500 certificate verify failed

I've installed `LWP::UserAgent Mozilla::CA` and `CACertOrg::CA` but it didnt fix the issue.

Is there any certificate I've to download for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Please try install  Crypt::SSLeay and  LWP::Protocol::https too.

A good reading about this issue: http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html

You could try this: [Scripts broke after upgrading LWP "certificate verify failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385846/scripts-broke-after-upgrading-lwp-certificate-verify-failed)

```
export PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0
```

Regards,

Comment: If `LWP::UserAgent` already knows about certificates (see the error message), then it's very probable that `Crypt::SSLeay` and `LWP::Protocol::https` are already installed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Both are already installed. I still get the error.

Comment: I edited my answer, that you could try to make 'unsafe' the certificate check.