# Perl LWP::Simple HTTPS error

Tags: perl, https, perl-module, lwp

I am trying to get the contents of a website and print. The code worked how I wanted it to work with a regular HTTP website, but it will not work with HTTPS.

I have looked up fixes for this issue, but they are not working in my program. This is the code I currently have:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use 5.014;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 );

getprint('https://<website>')or die 'Unable to get page';
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
500 Can't connect to <IP address>:443 (certificate verify failed) <URL:https://<website>>
```

Comment: That's not the code you ran. `LWP::Simple->new()` is a run-time error.

Comment: @ikegami You are right, I was testing to see if that worked at some point and must have copied the wrong code. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 } );
my $response = $ua->get('https://<website>');

if ( $response->is_success ) {
    print $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

See [LWP::Protocol::https](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04/lib/LWP/Protocol/https.pm) and [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm).

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385846/scripts-broke-after-upgrading-lwp-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: @CircuitB0T - As a clarification, did it work for you when `verify_hostname => 0` or `verify_hostname => 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 );` fails is probably because you misspelled `verify_hostname`.

I don't know why `$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;` failed, but it might because the environment var has to be set before the SSL library is loaded.